# Concurrent operations on django and database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am developing on Django 3 system. I am using mysql at backend. I have a design question. I have a system of doctors and patients. The patient is registered in the system. Doctors see the patient on their page and push a button and take patient. When 3 doctors open their pages at the same time, all of them will see the patient named Jennifer. Well, if they press the get jenifer patient button at the same time, wouldn't there be a conflict? How do I prevent this? What can i do for this concurrent operation to prevent exceptions.

Comment: Please add your code for assigning Doctors to Patients. You may be able to obtain row level locks on the DB to prevent these conflicts

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-concurrency/) tiny package (you can reimplement this, of course). Adding version field is a common solution.

Comment: Hello Iain, this part of the project is at design level. We havent code it yet. We couldnt decide if doctors choose patient. Or system automatically set patients to doctors. I affraid from conflict in case doctors try to choose patient at the same time same patient

Comment: @ivbtar Without code and models it's hard to give an answer, although there are a couple of things to look into: Make sure your database doesn't allow any corrupted/duplicated data, in the worst case your users will get 500 errors if their request is not first. If possible use [select_for_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to lock the rows you are updating so that any subsequent queries fail and can be handled